# Copy veryhidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works until sheet codenamed Template is VeryHidden.  Please help!!

```
y = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

namePrompt = InputBox("Enter a name for the new sheet", "Add Sheet")

If namePrompt = "" Then Exit Sub

Template.Copy after:=Worksheets(y - 1)

ActiveSheet.Name = namePrompt
```

Comment: Very Hidden. What does that mean?

Comment: @sam092 - "very hidden" can only be set via code or via the worksheet Properties pane in the VBEditor (choices are xlSheeVisible, xlSheetHidden, or xlSheetVeryHidden)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for letting me know :) I don't know about this property before.

Comment: Thank you Tim for that suggestion, it will certainly work if I unhide, copy then hide again.  I was hoping I missed some syntax because I can copy a range out of a veryhidden sheet, just not the entire sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test to see if the sheet is VeryHidden, and if so you can unhide it before copying...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim y, namePrompt, wasHidden

    y = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    namePrompt = InputBox("Enter a name for the new sheet", "Add Sheet")

    If namePrompt = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Template.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        Template.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        wasHidden = True
    End If

    Template.Copy after:=Worksheets(y - 1)

    ActiveSheet.Name = namePrompt

    If wasHidden Then Template.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure about vba, but are you sure wasHidden was initialized as false, else you have a possible bug.

Comment: @Toon: Yes, boolean variables are always initialized as false in VBA.